# How to get list data in modal?

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog

I want to get `listCategorie` from `getcategorie` function and put it in my modal but it comes empty! how can I fix that ?

here is it my code:

```
 getcategorie() {
    this.LCategorieService.getCategories(this.id).then((res )=> {
      this.listCategorie = res;
    })
  }
  
  async addNoteModal() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = false;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.data = {
      ismodal: true,
      idExamen: this.id,
      list:this.listCategorie ,


    };  console.log('aaaaaa',this.list);
 
    this.dialog.open(NoteModalComponent, dialogConfig);
    try {
      await this.getcategorie();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(" failed", error);
    }
  }
```

LCategorieService Service:

```
   getCategories(id: string): Promise<L_ExamenCategorie[]> {
    const response = this.httpClient.get<L_ExamenCategorie[]>(this.baseUrl + '/findcategories/' + id).toPromise();
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe also show the LCategorieService ?

Comment: Right. So: getcategorie() {
    return this.LCategorieService.getCategories(this.id)
  } and then in your addNoteModal function add const listCat = await this.getcategorie(); and add listCat to your data (list: listCat)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getcategorie()` before call `addNoteModal()`

```
async addNoteModal() {
   try {
       await this.getcategorie();
   } catch (error) {
       console.error(" failed", error);
   }

   const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
   dialogConfig.disableClose = false;
   dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
   dialogConfig.data = {
      ismodal: true,
      idExamen: this.id,
      list:this.listCategorie ,
   }; 
 
   this.dialog.open(NoteModalComponent, dialogConfig); 
  }
```

In your `NoteModalComponent` you need to get those data

```
data: any;

constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NoteModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
) {
   this.data = data.list
}
```